# JSON array returns syntax error

Tags: json

I'm trying to insert an array of strings in JSON but it isn't working.

json:

```
{
    "1": [{
        "id": "1",
        "title": "test 1",
        "galery": { "http://placehold.it/540x540" , "http://placehold.it/540x520"}
    }]
}
```

It's returning me syntax error on `"galery"` line but I can't figure out what is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an array, use:

```
"galery": ["http://placehold.it/540x540", "http://placehold.it/540x520"]
```

For named properties, use something like:

```
"galery": { url1:"http://placehold.it/540x540", url2:"http://placehold.it/540x520" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[ ]` for array of images in gallery. `{ }` will expect object (key/value pairs).

You can check valid JSON syntax at http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

Replace the braces with brackets.

```
{
"1": [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "test 1",
    "galery": [ "http://placehold.it/540x540" , "http://placehold.it/540x520" ]
}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect syntax at two places. Below is the correct one:

```
{
"1": {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "test 1",
    "galery": ["http://placehold.it/540x540" , "http://placehold.it/540x520"]
}
```

}